# Tryin to scale Unity buttons to a certain size range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have a set 2D buttons that I need to resize at runtime - the size of the buttons are determined by the width and height of the images being applied to the button (if the image is 17 inches by 17 inches, the button is 17 x 17 unity units, or the width and height of the rect transform).  The sizes of images themselves vary drastically, making the buttons appear really small (17 x 17), really big (900 x 850), or somewhere in the middle (630 x 560). To be clear, 630 x 560 is a good size for my project. I am looking to resize the buttons to be in a certain range, and have been experimenting with functions like `buttonObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(image.Width * 10f, item.Height * 10f);` Of course, this really only works for the small values and makes the larger values far too big. Currently working through this to find a solution that will help get all the images to retain their aspect ratio but fall into certain values. Is there a way to get numbers to fall into a range but not exceed the range? as well, can we ensure they retain the aspect ratio?